# JSON_VALUE возвращает ошибку

Tags: mysql, json

Имею такую структуру json в поле `payload`

```
{
    "opened": "none",
    "shopId": "158"
}
```

задача посчитать сколько ошибок в каждом магазине по таблице логов. делаю такой запрос:

```
"SELECT count(*) as count, JSON_VALUE(payload, '$.shopId') as shopId FROM warning_logs group by JSON_VALUE(payload, '$.shopId')"
```

получаю ошибку:

> ```
> Unhandled exception: SQL error: HY000 1548 Cannot load from
> mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted. SQL: SELECT count(*) as
> count, JSON_VALUE(payload, '$.shopId') as shopId FROM `warning_logs`
> where module = 'Shop' group by JSON_VALUE(payload, '$.shopId')
> ```

посоветуйте как выйти из ситуации

Comment: The table is probably corrupted. - А у вас таблица вообще живая? Если да, то скорее всего ваша версия MySQL сервера не поддерживает данный функционал.

Comment: таблица живая. вероятно причина в конфигурации или старой версии мускуля